# How to open two applications using one button?

Tags: vb.net

Hi sorry i am beginner  in vb.net Can you please help me how to open 2 applications using 1 button and what code should i use?

I already  try this code in 1 application
shell("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe") and it's work.

Comment: Firstly, don't use `Shell`. We're not using VB6. Call `Process.Start`. As for the problem, think a bit. If you know how to do something once, you know how to do it as many times as you want. You just do the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you'd like to be done when clicking the button.
If you want the button to open two applications at the same time, then you could just call 2 **Process.Start()** functions.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start("PATH for first application.")
    Dim x As Process = Process.Start("PATH for second application.")


End Sub
```

However, if you'd like to run two separate applications and have the second application wait until the first is closed then you can use the **.WaitForExit()** method. For example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start("PATH for first application.")
    p.WaitForExit()
    Dim x As Process = Process.Start("PATH for second application.")
    x.WaitForExit()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  How about  putting delay on second application? Should i use threading.thread. sleep('ms)?

Comment: @Jhoms 
Sure you can.  However, remember that Threading.Thread.Sleep can cause the PC to appear frozen for a short amount of time depending on the available resources of the PC.  So if it's for a pretty short delay (like 5 seconds or so) then you can probably get away with using Threading.Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @Jhoms

Also, if you think this helped you, could you vote it as the answer please! Helps the reputation on my account so I can actually use some of the other features.